# Compound Interest Calcultator - Issue with years

Tags: javascript, math

I'm having an issue with a simple compound interest calculator I'm developing, I set up a couple of parameters for it, one of which was years which is supposed to effect the value but I can't get it to work.
The math formula is

```
A = P(1+r/n)^nt

A   =   final amount
P   =   initial principal balance
r   =   interest rate
n   =   number of times interest applied per time period
t   =   number of time periods elapsed
```

I tried setting the number of times interest applied per time period but it wasn't working.

Here's my code:

```
var flag=true;
$("#b").click(function(){
    m=$("#c").val()* Math.pow((1+($("#j").val()/100)),$("#p").val());
    alert(m)
})

function mudou(){
    flag=true;
    var c=$("#c").val()
    m=(parseInt($("#c").val())+(12*parseInt($("#r").val())))* Math.pow((1+($("#j").val()/100)),(parseFloat($("#p").val())));
    console.log(parseFloat($("#p").val()))
    $("#m").val(m.toFixed(2)+"€");

}
function mudoum(){
    flag=false;
    m=$("#m").val()/( Math.pow((1+($("#j").val()/100)),(parseFloat($("#p").val()))));
    $("#c").val(m.toFixed(2)+"€");

}
function jp(){
    if(flag){
        mudou();

    }else{
        mudoum();

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Do you get any errors? What do you expect and what actually happens? Do you have a [mcve]?

Comment: It would also be helpful if you add the mathematical formulas you were trying to solve. Ex: `m = c * (1 + j / 100)^p`, etc.

Comment: What is `#b`? What is `#c`? It's very confusing that in your formula, `P` represents the principal, but it seems that in your code, you have a thing called `#p` which doesn't seem to be the same thing. What is `jp()`? Why is there a `flag`?